# How to creat Wt project in Mac and Netbeans

Tags: c++, macos, web, wt

I have successfully built and installed [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/) on my Mac, now I need to build sample apps and run it. I am unable to locate required libs on my machine. In example doc it says to do following:

```
g++ -o hello hello.cc -lwthttp -lwt
$ ./hello --docroot . --http-address 0.0.0.0 --http-port 9090
```

but I can't locate Include and libs file so that I can add in Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

After building Wt run this command in your Wt build dir.

`make install`

I guess it is missing in their tutorial http://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/projects/wt/wiki/Installing_Wt_on_Mac_OS_X_Leopard

Also to run hello.C you should use 'lboost_signals' flag as said here: http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/src/hello

`g++ -o hello hello.cpp -lwthttp -lwt -lboost_signals`